# Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got a error that

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: \
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'index_users_on_email': \ 
INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `id`) \
VALUES ('2017-01-05 13:05:14', '2017-01-05 13:05:14', 298486.
```

I wrote in home_controller,

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :find_user, only: [:index]

  def index
    @id = params[:id]
    @email = [:email]
    if @id == @user.id  && @email == @user.email
      render :text =>   "sucsess"
    else
      render :text =>   "fail"
    end
  end

  def create
    userData = UserData.new(create_params)
    user = User.find(params[:id]).to_json

    # エラー処理
    unless  userData.save
        @error_message = [memo.errors.full_messages].compact
    end
        end

  private
　 def find_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id]) # You should specify this code what are your comparing to.
    end
end
```

Before,I got a error that user variable is nil.

So,I debuted

```
user = User.find(params[:id]).to_json
```

and I got a error like above.

But in  localhost:3000, I got a error that

```
Routing Error undefined method `　' for HomeController:Class.
```

Therefore,I really cannot understand what is wrong.
How can I fix this error?

in routes.rb,I wrote

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: "home#index"
  get 'home/index'


  namespace :home, default: {format: :json} do
    resources :index, only: :create
  end
```

in test_helper.rb

```css
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

in home_controller_test.rb

```css
require 'test_helper'

class HomeControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

Comment: as i see, you are using devise, and by default the email field is unique for users. seems you've violated it.

Comment: @marmeladze thx, ur comments.Yes,Im using devices.So,how can I fix my error?

Comment: can you please share your test factory/fixture data?

Comment: @marmeladze what do u mean "factory/fixture data"?Controller?model??

Comment: no, `Minitest::UnexpectedError:` is an output from a test case. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html
generally we create fixtures or factories to run tests. so they become a bit realistic.

Comment: @marmeladze       sure, thx,I edited my codes

Comment: please add fixtures. they are yaml files (.yml) inside `test/fixtures/` folder.

Comment: @marmeladze what should I write fixtures?